# OrientDB query specific type of edges

Tags: orientdb

I have this db (definition) type schema:

```
Type.Vertex.1 --(Type.Edge.1)--> T.V.2
T.V.1 --(T.E.1)--> T.V.3
T.V.1 --(T.E.1)--> T.V.4
```

...

I want to query all `T.V.1`s where has edge `T.E.1` and `in` type be `T.V.3` only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select from <class-name> where <property-name> = "T.V.1" and out("<edge-name>").<property-name> contains 'T.V.3'
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: tnx for ur comment, but as I say T.V.1 is type name not value like User, City, Car, ...

Comment: so, could you explain better? Because from your schema it seems that T.V.1 is a vertex.